# Core Data Fetch according to ids from another entity

Tags: entity-framework, core-data, reference

I have two entity in Core data.

First one is as follow:-
Building Entity .h file

```
@interface Permits : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sec;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phoneNo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * submitDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * inputDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * projectName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * permitNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * buildingDep;

@end
```

Favorites building entity .h file

```
@interface FavPermits : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * permitNum;

@end
```

User is allow to add Building into their favorites section. Now, i want to fetch data from building according to permitNum that is available in favorites building entity.

SQL query is as follow :-

```
Select * from Building as b, favBuilding as fb where b.permitNumber = fb.permitNum
```

Comment: Have you looked into using an instance of `NSFetchRequest` or `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: yeah i am using NSFetchedResultsController to fetch. but i want to fetch data using join. I know core data doesn't use join. So, is there any alternative ?

Comment: In your data model, have you added a relationship in your `Permits` entity and the inverse in your `FavPermits` entity? That will create the join you're looking for.

Comment: yes i did. But but how can i perform a fetch function ? i am using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.